# QSWAT for Linux

Tags: qgis, qswat

I want use SWAT model, but I use Ubuntu 18.04. Besides that, I use QGIS. I know there is a SWAT version for QGIS in Windows, but I didn't find information about Linux distros. 
Is there a forecast for the QSWAT version for any Linux distro?

Comment: In this link https://swat.tamu.edu/software/qswat/ says that is only for Windows.

Comment: @xunilk please post your comment as an answer so this thread can be marked as answered

Comment: @underdark  I posted my comment as an answer. I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible use QSWAT in Ubuntu or any GNU/Linux. In this link:

https://swat.tamu.edu/software/qswat/

it says that is only for Windows.

Comment: Apparently it only works for QGIS 2.6 as well which can be downloaded from the same page.

Comment: The website still says that QSWAT is only for Windows, but the manual indicates that it will run on Linux and MacOS as well: https://2468211880-files.gitbook.io/~/files/v0/b/gitbook-x-prod.appspot.com/o/spaces%2FT47EY0rpheOA7rIcPNO2%2Fuploads%2FcGkm1KeShJdTBaiayxDD%2FQSWATPlus%20Manual_v2.2.pdf?alt=media&token=688fc878-537d-4789-9bed-2539dd3fd26f

I haven't tried this out yet, but can hopefully provide a more useful answer later.

Comment: @user1521655 Thanks for share! I will testing too.